# Bochner Integral: Integrability

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, measure-theory

**Attention**

This question has been slightly modified!!

**Reference**

It is related to: [Bochner Integral: Axioms](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1042887/79762)

**Problem**

Given a measure space $\Omega$ and a Banach space $E$.

Consider Bochner measurable functions $F\in\mathcal{B}$.

Then integrability is given by:
$$\int\|F-S_n\|\mathrm{d}\mu\to0\iff\int\|F\|\mathrm{d}\mu<\infty$$

On the one hand it holds:
$$\int\|F\|\mathrm{d}\mu\leq\int\|F-S_N\|\mathrm{d}\mu+\int\|S_N\|\mathrm{d}\mu<1+\infty$$

What about the converse?

**Addendum**

There's another didactic definition of integrability:
$$F\in\mathcal{L}:\iff\int\|S_m-S_n\|\mathrm{d}\mu\to0\quad(S_n\to F)$$
Certainly, one has for a suitable approximation:
$$S_n\to F:\quad\int\|S_m-S_n\|\mathrm{d}\mu\leq\int\|F-S_m\|\mathrm{d}\mu+\int\|F-S_n\|\mathrm{d}\mu\to0$$
But what about the converse here?

**Caution**

Although an integral gives the impression of measurability one should keep in mind that:
$$\int\|F-S_n\|\mathrm{d}\mu\to0\quad\nRightarrow\quad F\in\mathcal{B}$$
*(For a counterexample see: [Bochner Integral: Approximability](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1051586/79762))*

Comment: First, you will need some assumptions on $f$, e.g. Bochner-measurability. (Otherwise, $\Vert f\Vert$ could be measurable without $f$ being measurable). Second, what is your definition of the Bochner-integral?

Comment: @PhoemueX: Let $f$ be Bochner measurable resp. Bochner integrable if there exists a sequence resp. $L_1$-cauchy sequence of simple functions converging pointwise a.e. $s_n(\omega)\to f(\omega)$.

Comment: @PhoemueX: Ah I get your point - will add it to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Proof**

Suppose $\int\|F\|\mathrm{d}\mu<\infty$.

By measurability there is a simple approximation:
$$S_n\in\mathcal{S}:\quad S_n\to F$$
Bound the approximation via cutoff:
$$\|S'_n\|\leq2\|F\|:\quad S'_n\to F$$
so it gets an integrable dominant:
$$\int\|F-S'_n\|\mathrm{d}\mu\leq\int3\|F\|\mathrm{d}\mu<\infty$$
Concluding that the integrals vanish:
$$\int\|F-S'_n\|\mathrm{d}\mu\to0$$

**Addendum**

Given a simple cauchy approximation one has:
$$S_n\to F:\quad\int\left|\|S_m\|-\|S_n\|\right|\mathrm{d}\mu\leq\int\|S_m-S_n\|\mathrm{d}\mu\to0$$
So it is absolutely integrable:
$$\int\|F\|\mathrm{d}\mu=\lim_n\int\|S_n\|\mathrm{d}\mu<\infty$$
*(The hard work was done in: [Amann & Escher Integral vs. Lebesgue Integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1051056/79762))*

**Shortcut**

By Fatou this turns into an amazing one-liner:
$$\int\|F-S_n\|\mathrm{d}\mu\leq\liminf_n\int\|S_m-S_n\|\mathrm{d}\mu\to0$$

Answer (score 2):

You can find a clear proof in chapter IV of J. Diestel's *Sequences and series in Banach spaces* (p. 26).

Here is another proof.

Denote by $(\Omega, \Sigma, \mu)$ the underlying probability space, and by $X$ the involved Banach space. I guess that you implicitely assume that the function $f:\Omega\to X$ is Bochner-measurable.

Assume that $\Vert f\Vert$ is integrable. We want to show that there is a sequence of simple functions $(s_n)$ such that $\int_\Omega \Vert s_n-f\Vert\, d\mu\to 0$. Equivalently, given $\varepsilon >0$, we need to find a simple function $s$ such that $\int_\Omega \Vert s-f\Vert\leq\varepsilon$.

Since $f$ is Bochner-measurable, there is a sequence of simple functions $(\phi_n)$ converging almost everywhere to $f$. If we set $A_n=\{ x\in\Omega;\; \Vert \phi_n(x)-f(x)\Vert\geq\varepsilon\}$, then $\mu(A_n)\to 0$.

Since $\Vert f\Vert$ is integrable, one can find $\delta>0$ such that $\int_A \Vert f\Vert\, d\mu<\varepsilon$ for any measurable set $A$ satisfying $\mu(A)<\delta$. Choose $n$ such that $\mu(A_n)<\delta$, and define $s:\Omega\to X$ by $s=0$ on $A_n$ and $s=\phi_n$ outside $A_n$. This is a simple function, and 
$$ \int_\Omega \Vert s-f\Vert=\int_{A_n}\Vert f\Vert\, d\mu+\int_{\Omega\setminus A_n}\Vert \phi_n-f\Vert\leq \varepsilon+\varepsilon \, ,$$
where the first $\varepsilon$ comes from the fact that $\mu(A_n)<\delta$, and the second one from the fact that $\Vert \phi_n-f\Vert<\varepsilon$ on $\Omega\setminus A_n$. So we are done, upon replacing $\varepsilon$ by $\varepsilon/2$ in the beginning.

Comment: I hope you don't mind that I changed the accepted answer - I guess I found a shorter one meanwhile. Still you got my (+1).

Comment: @Freeze_S Don't worry! By the way, I didn't know it was possible to accept an answer to one of its own questions.

Answer (score 1):

$(\Rightarrow)$ Since
$$\int \big|\|f\|-\|s_n\|\big|d\lambda \leq \int \big\|f-s_n\big\|d\lambda \rightarrow 0$$
we have
$$\left|\int \|s_n\|d\lambda-\int\|s_m\|d\lambda\right|\leq \int \big|\|s_n\|-\|s_m\|\big|d\lambda \leq \int \big|\|f\|-\|s_n\|\big|d\lambda+\int \big|\|f\|-\|s_m\|\big|d\lambda \rightarrow 0$$
then, 
$$ \left(\int \|s_n\| d\lambda\right)_{n\in\mathbb N}\;\text{ is a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb R$, therefore, it is convergent sequence.}$$
Suppose that $\lim\int \|s_n\|=M$. Thus, 
$$\int \|f\|d\lambda\leq \int\|f-s_n\|d\lambda+\int\|s_n\|d\lambda\,,\quad\forall\,n\in\mathbb N$$
taking the limit as $n\rightarrow\infty$, 
$$\int \|f\|d\lambda\leq 0 + M = M<\infty$$
Note that $\|f\|$ is real number, then what we had to show is that this was Lebesgue integrable.

$(\Leftarrow)$ Let us assume that $f:X\rightarrow E$ is Bochner-measurable and $f(X)$ is separable in $E$. The above assumptions imply that there is a sequence $\{s_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ of simple functions such that $s_n\rightarrow f$ and $\|s_n\|\leq2\|f\|$. We have then $\|f-s_n\|\rightarrow 0$, and 
$$\|f-s_n\|\leq \|f\|+\|s_n\|\leq 3\|f\|$$
Define the measurable function $g_k=\|f-s_k\|$ and note that $g_k\leq 3\|f\|$. As $\|f\|$ is integrable function, we can use the dominated convergence theorem, then
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int \|f-s_k\| d\lambda=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int g_k d\lambda = 0$$
This shows that $f$ is Bochner-integrable. $\#$

There may be some error in the details, but I think the idea is correct.

Comment: Your proof would be perfect if you gave some details to explain how you can ensure the "domination" $\Vert s_n\Vert\leq 2\Vert f\Vert$.

Comment: Really, this detail is not trivial and is a consequence of the fact that $f(X)$ is separable in $E$. Assuming this fact, let $\{y_i\,{:}\,i\in\mathbb N\}$ suck that
$$f(X)=\overline{\{y_i\,{:}\,i\in\mathbb N\}}$$

Comment: Enlarging this set by an at most countable number of vectors if
necessary, we may assume that $y_i\neq 0$ for all $i\in\mathbb N$. For $i,N\in\mathbb N$ define
$$\hat A_i^N = \{x\in X\;{:}\; \|f(x)\|\geq 1/N\,,\;\|f(x)-y_i\|< 1/N\}$$

Comment: As an intersection of Borel sets the $\hat A_i^N$ are Borel sets as well. Fixing $N\in\mathbb N$, we obtain a disjoint decomposition $\{A_i^N\}_{i\in\mathbb N}$ of $\bigcup_{i\in\mathbb N}\hat A_i^N$ by setting
$$A_1^N := \hat A_1^N\,,\quad A_i^N:= \hat A_i^N\setminus\left[\bigcup_{j=1}^{i-1}A_j^N\right]$$
for all $i\geq 2$. Indeed, given $x\in\bigcup_{i\in\mathbb N}\hat A_i^N$ we have
$$x\in A_{i_0}^N\quad \Leftrightarrow \quad\text{$i_0$ is the smallest number such that $x\in\hat A_{i_0}^N$}$$

Comment: Since $\{y_i\,{:}\,i\in\mathbb N\}$ is dense in $f(X)$, for each $N\in\mathbb N$ we have
$$\bigcup_{i\in\mathbb N}A_i^N = \bigcup_{i\in\mathbb N}\hat A_i^N = \{x\in X\;{:}\;\|f(x)\|\geq 1/N\}$$

Comment: Now we can define the desired sequence $\{s_N\}_{N\in\mathbb N}$ of simple functions. For each $N\in\mathbb N$
$$s_N(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{crr}0& & \text{ if $x\not\in\bigcup_{m,i=1}^N A_i^m$} \\ y_{i_{N,x}} && \text{ if $x\in\bigcup_{m,i=1}^N A_i^m$} \end{array}\right.$$

Comment: where the number $i_{N,x}\in\{1,2,\ldots,N\}$ is determined as follows: Take the largest integer $m_{N,x}\leq N$ such that $x\in\bigcup_{i=1}^N A_i^{m_{N,x}}$, as this union is disjoint we define 
$i_{N,x}$ as the unique number such that $x\in A_{i_{N,x}}^{m_{N,x}}$ (this implies $i_{N,x}\leq N$). Hence $s_N$ takes only values in $\{0,y_1,\ldots,y_N\}$.

Comment: Furthermore, if $x\in A_{i_{N,x}}^{m_{N,x}}$ then 
$$\|s_N(x)\|=\|y_{i_{N,x}}\|\leq \|y_{i_{N,x}}-f(x)\|+\|f(x)\|\leq \frac{1}{m_{N,x}}+\|f(x)\|\leq 2\|f(x)\|$$
Formally, we should also show that $s_N$ are measurable functions, but I think this is enough to understand the existence of these simple functions dominated.

Comment: OK, that's great, thanks!