# Bochner Integral: Axioms

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

**Disclaimer**

It is meant to record. See: [Answer own Question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

It is written as question. Have fun! :)

**Reference**

It is taken from the original paper: [S. Bochner, Integration](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm20/fm20127.pdf)

It is related to: [Bochner Integral: Integrability](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/916077/79762)

**Definition**

Given a measure space $\Omega$ and a Banach space $E$.

Consider Bochner measurable functions $S_n\to F$.

Suppose Bochner integrability as $\int\|F\|\mathrm{d}\mu<\infty$.

Denote the abstract Bochner integral by $\int F\mathrm{d}\mu$.

Define the Bochner integral axiomatically by:
$$\text{(L)}\quad\int(F+G)\mathrm{d}\mu=\int F\mathrm{d}\mu+\int F\mathrm{d}\mu,\,\int\lambda F\mathrm{d}\mu=\lambda\int F\mathrm{d}\mu$$
$$\text{(N)}:\quad\left\|\int F\mathrm{d}\mu\right\|\leq\int\|F\|\mathrm{d}\mu$$
$$\text{(DC)}:\quad\|F_n\|\leq h:\quad F_n\to F\implies\int F\mathrm{d}\mu\to\int F\mathrm{d}\mu\quad\left(\int h\mathrm{d}\mu<\infty\right)$$

And especially for finite measures:
$$\text{(C)}:\quad\int C\mathrm{d}\mu=C\mu(\Omega)$$

**Construction**

This forces the integral for simple functions to become:
$$S=\sum_{k=1}^KS_k\chi(A_k):\quad\int S\mathrm{d}\mu=\sum_{k=1}^KS_k\mu(A_k)$$

Now, for Bochner measurable functions Bochner integrability should determine the integral, too:
$$S_n\to F\implies\int S_n\mathrm{d}\mu\to\int F\mathrm{d}\mu$$

But how to apply dominated convergence therefore:
$$\|F-S_n\|\to0\implies\|S_n\|\leq\|F\|$$
*(I got it now; in any way, you are warmly encouraged to do give an answer, too!!)*

**Discardure**

Introduce the restricted integral through $\int_A F\mathrm{d}\mu:=\int\chi_AF\mathrm{d}\mu$.

There is another axiom which seems not independent of the others:
$$\text{(S)}:\quad\int_A F\mathrm{d}\mu=\sum_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\int_{A_k}F\mathrm{d}\mu\quad\left(A=\bigsqcup_{k\in\mathbb{N}}A_k\right)$$
*(Is it really independent?)*

Comment: Is the reference really Bochner's original paper?

Comment: Isn't the axiom on disjoint sums redundant? (S)

Comment: Dude, you don't have to ask yourself questions in the comments also.

Comment: @Michael: Haha ^^ no these are really questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can choose an appropriate sequence:
$$\|F-S_n\|\downarrow0$$
This way one obtains a dominant:
$$\|F-S_n\|\leq\|F-S_0\|:\quad\int\|F-S_0\|\mathrm{d}\mu\leq\int\|F\|\mathrm{d}\mu+\int\|S_0\|\mathrm{d}\mu<\infty+\infty$$
Thus by dominated convergence and linearity:
$$\int F\mathrm{d}\mu-\int S_n\mathrm{d}\mu=\int(F-S_n)\mathrm{d}\mu\to0$$
*(For more details see: [Bochner Integral: Integrability](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/916077/79762))*