# Bochner Integral: Measurability

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Given a measure space $\Omega$.

Consider plain functions $f$.

Define the plain integral as usual:
$$f\geq0:\quad\int f\mathrm{d}\mu:=\sup_{s\leq f}\int s\mathrm{d}\mu$$

Do vanishing integrals imply measurability:
$$\int|f-s_n|\mathrm{d}\mu\to0\implies s_{n_k}\to f\implies f\in\mathcal{M}$$
*(Be aware that the usual proof heavily depends upon measurability!)*

Have a guess! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No, they don't!**

Consider a Vitali set $V\subseteq[0,1]$.

Then one has trivially:
$$\int|\chi_V-0|\mathrm{d}\mu\equiv\mu_*(V)=0$$
However, it is not even measurable!